# Count IDs of groups if one variable are equal in a group

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R like the following:

```
  Group.ID status
1        1   open
2        1   open
3        2   open
4        2 closed
5        2 closed
6        3   open
```

I want to count the number of IDs under the condition: when all status are "open" for same ID number. For example, Group ID 1 has two observations, and their status are both "open", so that's one for my count. Group ID 2 is not because not all status are open for group ID 2.

I can count the rows or the group IDs under conditions. However I don't know how to apply "all status equal to one value for a group" logic.

**DATA.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Group.ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), status = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("closed", "open"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Group.ID", 
"status"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, both using `base R`, one more complicated with `aggregate` and the other with `tapply`. If you just want the total count of `Group.ID` matching you request, I suggest that you use the second solution.

```
agg <- aggregate(status ~ Group.ID, df1, function(x) as.integer(all(x == "open")))
sum(agg$status)
#[1] 2

sum(tapply(df1$status, df1$Group.ID, FUN = function(x) all(x == "open")))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I changed the data.frame to to the following: df1 <-
structure(list(Group.ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), status = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("closed", "open"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Group.ID", 
"status"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")   The answer should be Group.ID 1 has all status of "open", so count of group ID would be 1, rather than 2.

Comment: @JasonXu I have just tried the very same code with your new data and the output is `1`, like you expect it to be. It seems to me that you should try those two solutions and see if they fit your problem, apparently they do.

Answer (score 0):

a `dplyr`solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group.ID) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(status == "open") == 2) %>%
  nrow()
```